# ansible update debian from fedora

Tags: debian, fedora, ansible

So I got a bunch of Raspberry Pies, and I'm getting tired of logging on to each one to update them. So I got ansible to get that done. I'm running ansible from a Fedora laptop, and I got the python-dnf module to update all the Fedora Pies.  Now, I also have one running Debian, and every time I update that one, ansible tells me to consider the apt module. The docs mention python-apt and aptitude. I've searched far and wide, but I can't find those Fedora packages. Do they exist (and if so, where to find them)?

Answer (score 0):

Ansible prints that error message because you are using a generic module (`shell` or `command`) when there is a `apt` module. The `apt` module has a Python dependency `python-apt` on the host that executes the module, which is in your case the raspberry pi. You will need to install that package using a generic module or `pip` on your rpi. For further explanation take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078976/do-ansible-modules-run-locally-or-on-the-remote-host) 
You can install `python-apt` package via pip on your Fedora host but that's not the cause of the warning. It's also just a warning, reminding you that using the `command` module is not a best practice when there is a specific module for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my questions. However, I though you have to install the modules on the machine that you run ansible on, not on the target hosts, as modules are (I think) another way to compose the commands to be run remotely.

Comment: Yeah. Its not intuitive. That's why I linked the question. What happens is: Ansible creates a small script for the task. Copies to remote host. Execute on remote host. And in case of apt module the script makes use of the apt Python module. that's why it needs to be present on the remote system.